# sql migration - decoupling deployment from execution

Tags: asp.net-core, migration

We have a .NET c# solution that uses AliaSQL to run database migrations / to build the backend. I have a situation where we need to write some SQL Server logic that will

- copy records from Table A to Table B based on some logic.  It's not a straight copy.
- must be triggered at a specific point in time, not by the pipeline.
- is a one time only script.
- team wants to deploy the script via our pipeline.

It doesn't fit the AliaSQL paradigm because we want to control when the migration is triggered.  (likely a scheduled cron job)
in this particular case, it will only be needed once.

Just looking for ideas / a pattern on how others handle these types of one off scripts.

Comment: What about a stored proc that gets created by a data migration. After being executed manually maybe, then someone adds another migration to delete the stored proc?

Comment: I don't believe there is a pattern for this.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the script part of a stored procedure which schedules itself.  You find the basic details how to write such a stored procedure in TSQL [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1769443) from 2009. AliaSQL can install this SP by some script in the [Everytime folder](https://github.com/ClearMeasure/AliaSQL/wiki/Getting-started) and run it immediately, but the execution time of the core parts will be controlled by the logic inside the SP, which defers its execution until a certain point in time is reached.

The SP may also remove itself once it was executed successfully, to leave the DB in a state as if the data migration was done by an ordinary SQL script. [This SO post from 2014 says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937006/can-a-sql-stored-procedure-drop-itself-and-continue-execution) this is definitely possible. Or, the SP is left in the database forever, so the SP installation script tests for its existence and when the SP is already there, it assumes it was already executed. This makes the whole process idempotent.

Comment: I'm very familiar with a stored proc ... but as far as scheduling itself... i see the example is on database start up.  But I would like to know other trigger options.  What should I google?

Comment: @dot: the "database startup" is completely irrelevant in the example. The point is, a SP can wait for doing certain actions until a defined point in time (as you said, like a cron job). Maybe you read the SO post again?

Comment: I was a little confused by the SO answer as well. I think the answer mentions rebooting the database so it runs the stored proc right away. If you don't reboot, I imagine the stored proc runs at the next scheduled time. Am I interpreting that correctly, Doc?

Comment: @GregBurghardt: the OP mentioned AliaSQL and a pipeline. I took a short look into the manual: it is a tool for DB migrations which executes SQL scripts whenever someone says it has to. Hence installation and initial execution of the SP should be just a script in the Everytime folder used by AliaSQL.

Comment: A stored proc that destroys itself after executing *absolutely must* be put in `MissionImpossible.sql` - this stored proc will self-destruct after completion. But then we have copyright issues...

Comment: @GregBurghardt: ;-)  after thinking twice about it, I think not deleting itself maybe the better option, see my edit.

Comment: There is something philosophically elegant about testing for your own existence, and upon discovering you exist, assuming you have already fulfilled your purpose.